# asp.net c# SqlDataSource timout problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to extend the timeout of an SqlDataSource beyond 30 second (Seems to be the default). I'm trying to run a stored procedure that has to run through 100,000s of records. During busy periods it times out. I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS 6.0 on 2003 server.

**Error Message:**
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I've tried to no avail to extend the timeout:

```
< asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="604800" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SuperNARIC %>" SelectCommand="selectStatus" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" onselecting="dsTest_Selecting" >
    <SelectParameters>
        < asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCar" Name="CountryID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    < /SelectParameters>
< /asp:SqlDataSource>



protected void dsTest_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265901/943095), this worked for me.

You can increase the Timeout property like this

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        }
```

Setting timeout to 0 means no timeout

Answer (score 10):

There are two types of timeout: **ConnectionTimeout** and **CommandTimeout**:

**ConnectionTimeout**
Determines the maximum time your app will wait to establish a connection to your server.

**CommandTimeout**:
Max time allowed for a command to execute.

Make sure you set both. In the **Comand**:

```
 command.CommandTimeout = 300;
```

Note: This can be implemented in the `Selecting` event should your command be part of a DataSource. `e.Command.CommandTimeout = 0;` A value of `0` means to wait indefinitely.

And **connection string**:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cs = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
cs.ConnectTimeout = 300;
```

Or:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MyDB; Integrated Security=True;Pooling=True;connection timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Note**: Try setting the connection string timeout globally, perhaps in your config file.

Comment: Hi, I have the following in my web.config: Connection Timeout=180

Comment: Cool, pump it up to 500 just for testing purposes and see.

Answer (score 3):

Timeout is generally set in your connection string.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for complete examples.

Comment: Hi, I have the following in my web.config: Connection Timeout=180

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure both your `CommandTimeout` and your `ConnectionString`'s `Connect Timeout` are set to prevent timing out on long-running stored procedures.  If you don't set the connection timeout, you'll timeout before the stored procedure is finished, even if the stored procedure command itself hasn't timed out.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I have the following in my web.config: Connection Timeout=180

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
  <script runat="server">
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
    e.Command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    }
    </script>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="Your Connection String" 
ProviderName="Teradata.Client.Provider"
SelectCommand="A SELECT COMMAND THAT TAKES A LONG TIME"
DataSourceMode="DataSet"
onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect Timeout/Connection Timeout/Timeout
Default Value - 15 sec
The length of time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to the server before terminating the attempt and generating an error. Valid values are greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 2147483647.

```
string myconstr = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
    + "Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30"
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I have the following in my web.config: Connection Timeout=180

Answer (score 0):

The Maximum Connection Time Out Value can be 2147483647. Try setting the Connection Timeout value into your Connection string in your Web Config as below

`<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=144681;Initial Catalog=Customer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=yyyyy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: And Add `<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MyDB; Integrated Security=True;Pooling=True;connection timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` into the `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>`

Answer (score -1):

There's a timeout for both the SQL and the page response time.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 120; 
e.Command.CommandTimeout = 120;
```