# Timeout Error for sql data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datasource

Error code:

> Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding.

Can someone provide me with code I can copy and paste so I can change the default timeout? I'm not sure where to put it into this code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Proxy Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Proxy Report"></asp:Label>

</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ISALog1ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="ProxyReport" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is much more likely to mean that your connection string is wrong.

Comment: There's some help on this over here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286685/asp-net-c-sharp-sqldatasource-timout-problems

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can increase the Timeout property like this

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        }
```

Setting timeout to 0 means no timeout

Comment: Don't forget to attach the event handler if you are creating the datasource on code behind: `SqlDataSource1.Selecting += SqlDataSource1_Selecting;`